# Getting limit of natural logarithm without l'Hospital $\left(\lim_{n \to \inf} \frac{1}{n\,\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$

Tags: limits

How does
$$\lim_{n \to \inf} \frac{1}{n\,\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} = 1?$$

I mean, $\frac{1}{n} = 0$ if $n\to\inf$. So the paranthesis would become one. And $\ln(1)=0$. Hence the demoninator becomes zero. Hence there is no result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's wrong to write $1/n=0$ when $n\to \infty $. However $1/n\to 0$ if $n\to \infty $. Notice that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n\ln(1+1/n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(1+1/n)-\ln(1)}{1/n-0}}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}$$ where $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: The denominator doesn't go to zero because there is a $n$ which goes to $\infty$, so you have to evaluate the indeterminate $0\cdot\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice by properties of limits and logs, the limit is the same as

$$\frac{1}{ \ln  \lim_{n\uparrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n }.$$

Do you recognize $\lim_{n\uparrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n $?

Comment: ok, then it would be ln(e)=1 and 1/1 = 1 ... but how are you allowed to just remove the n in the denominator and attach it to the parenthesis?

Comment: Convince yourself that you can rewrite the limit in the way I described. Remember properties of logs, and remember that a limit and a function commute if the function is continuous!

Comment: @Helpless properties of logs: coefficient of the log is an exponent of what's inside the log

Comment: thanks, now I understand

Comment: @Helpless no prob. pls upvote if you find it helpful!

Comment: I can't, I do not have enough points, but I marked u as the accepted answer. sorry :'(

Comment: no prob, thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at the denominator, the behavior of natural log at x approaches infinity is like 1/n, because 1/n = $0$ as x approaches infinity; so one could rewrite that stuff as n * 1/n, therefore n cancels out with the n in the denominator. you have 1.